# Does hook_node_access_records() and hook_node_grants() change permissions for existing nodes?

Tags: 6, users

When I install a new module containing `hook_node_access_records()` and `hook_node_grants()`, Does it change permissions for existing nodes? Or it affects only on new nodes?

If it doesn't change permissions for existing nodes, Is there a way to rebuild node_access table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement hook_enable() and call node_access_needs_rebuild(TRUE), see [user_relationship_node_access_enable()](http://api.worldempire.ch/api/user_relationships/user_relationship_node_access--user_relationship_node_access.install/function/user_relationship_node_access_enable/7-1) for an example.

That doesn't actually do much on its own, but Drupal will then automatically print a message to administrators and inform them that the permissions need to be rebuild and also includes a link to the place where this can be done.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it affect the old node, but I think no. If you need to rebuild the access, can go in Content management -> Post settings and you'll see a form to allow you rebuild permissions.